# Multirow results in text overlapping border

Tags: tables, multirow

when using multirow in the following example, the content of the multirow cell is placed above the cell border. Is there any means to remove the border automatically where multirow is used?

Code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|p{4cm}|}
\hline
Titel & Dat. & Künstler & Nationalität & Technik & Maße=(H,B,Einheit) & Ikonographie\\ \hline
Der Mönch am Meer & 1808 & \multirow{2}{*}{Caspar David Friedrich} & Deutschland & Öl auf Leinwand &(110,171.5,cm) & (...)\\ \hline
Frau am Fenster & 1822 & & Deutschland & Öl auf Leinwand &(44.1,37,cm) & (...)\\ \hline
Die Welle & 1869 & Gustave Courbet & Frankreich & Öl auf Leinwand & (112,144,cm) & (...)\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks and best,
Christian

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe).

Comment: Yes, replace the 3rd `\hline` with `\cline{1-2}\cline{4-7}`

Comment: @karlkoeller: I was aware of this solution, but is there a means to remove the boarder **automatically**?

Comment: @Chris Sorry I didn't understand the question in the OP... Unfortunately, I don't know an **automatic** method.

Comment: @Chris -- To remove the boundary, modify the 'table spec' on both sides as c|...|c, remove the first \hline and the last \hline in the table and Karlkoeller's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the package `cals`, which cares about decorations:

[image: decorations automatically correct in calstable]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{cals}
\begin{document}
\fontspec{texgyretermes-regular.otf}\small
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{3.3cm}{1cm}{4cm}{3cm}{3cm}{3.3cm}{2.3cm}}
\brow
\cell{Titel}
\cell{Dat.}
\cell{Künstler}
\cell{Nationalität}
\cell{Technik}
\cell{Maße=(H,B,Einheit)}
\cell{Ikonographie}
\erow
\brow
\cell{Der Mönch am Meer}
\cell{1808}
\nullcell{ltr}
\cell{Deutschland}
\cell{Öl auf Leinwand}
\cell{(110,171.5,cm)}
\cell{(...)}
\erow
\brow
\cell{Frau am Fenster}
\cell{1822}
\nullcell{lbr}\spancontent{%
  %\vfil % uncomment to align middle
  Caspar David Friedrich}
\cell{Deutschland}
\cell{Öl auf Leinwand}
\cell{(44.1,37,cm)}
\cell{(...)}
\erow
\brow
\cell{Die Welle}
\cell{1869}
\cell{Gustave Courbet}
\cell{Frankreich}
\cell{Öl auf Leinwand}
\cell{(112,144,cm)}
\cell{(...)}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```